# Gitlab CI failure with JHipster

Tags: gradle, jhipster, gitlab-ci

I can build my JHipster gateway with gradle from the development machine, but when I give it to the Gitlab CI I get this error at the 'gradle-package' step:

```
92 $ ./gradlew bootJar -Pprod -x check --no-daemon
93 To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
94 Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
95 > Task :bootBuildInfo
96 > Task :nodeSetup SKIPPED
97 > Task :npmSetup SKIPPED
98 > Task :npmInstall UP-TO-DATE
99 > Task :webpack FAILED
100 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
101 * What went wrong:
102 Execution failed for task ':webpack'.
103 > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
```

This is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
        - .gradle/
stages:
    - check
    - build
    - test
    - analyze
    - package
    - release
    - deploy
before_script:
    - export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS="false"
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - ./gradlew npm_install -PnodeInstall --no-daemon
nohttp:
    stage: check
    script:
        - ./gradlew checkstyleNohttp --no-daemon

gradle-compile:
    stage: build
    script:
        - ./gradlew compileJava -x check -PnodeInstall --no-daemon
    artifacts:
        paths:
          - build/classes/
          - build/generated/
        expire_in: 1 day

gradle-test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ./gradlew test -PnodeInstall --no-daemon
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
        paths:
            - build/test-results/
            - build/jacoco/
        expire_in: 1 day

gradle-integration-test:

    stage: test
    script:
        - ./gradlew integrationTest -PnodeInstall --no-daemon 
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: build/test-results/integrationTest/TEST-*.xml
        paths:
            - build/test-results/
            - build/jacoco/
        expire_in: 1 day

frontend-test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - ./gradlew npm_run_test -PnodeInstall --no-daemon
    artifacts:
        reports:
            junit: build/test-results/TESTS-results-jest.xml
        paths:
            - build/test-results/
            - build/jacoco/
        expire_in: 1 day


gradle-package:
    stage: package
    script:
        - ./gradlew bootJar -Pprod -x check --no-daemon
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build/libs/*.jar
            - build/classes
        expire_in: 1 day

# Uncomment the following line to use gitlabs container registry. You need to adapt the REGISTRY_URL in case you are not using gitlab.com
docker-push:
    stage: release
    variables:
        REGISTRY_URL: 10.1.10.58
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    dependencies:
        - gradle-package
    script:
        - ./gradlew jib -Pprod -Djib.allowInsecureRegistries=true -Djib.to.image=$IMAGE_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username="gitlab-ci-token"  -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
    }
    dependencies {
        //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "maven-publish"
    id "idea"
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.springframework.boot"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea"
    id "net.ltgt.apt"
    id "org.liquibase.gradle"
    id "org.sonarqube"
    id "io.spring.nohttp"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

group = "com.rps.png"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

description = ""

sourceCompatibility=1.8
targetCompatibility=1.8
assert System.properties["java.specification.version"] == "1.8" || "11" || "12" || "13" || "14"

apply from: "gradle/docker.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/sonar.gradle"
//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty("prod") || project.hasProperty("gae")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("war")) {
    apply from: "gradle/war.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("gae")) {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}"
        }
    }
    appengineStage.dependsOn thinResolve
}

if (project.hasProperty("zipkin")) {
    apply from: "gradle/zipkin.gradle"
}

idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += files("node_modules")
    }
}

eclipse {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += ["build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"]
            }
        }
    }
}

defaultTasks "bootRun"

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.rps.png.GatewayuApp"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"

    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }
    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = "Execute integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    include "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"

    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }

    if (project.hasProperty('testcontainers')) {
        environment 'spring.profiles.active', 'testcontainers'
    }

    // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
    // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
    // ignoreFailures true
    reports.html.enabled = false
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn test
}

task integrationTestReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
    reportOn integrationTest
}

if (!project.hasProperty("runList")) {
    project.ext.runList = "main"
}

project.ext.diffChangelogFile = "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/" + new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_changelog.xml"

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver "org.h2.Driver"
            url "jdbc:h2:file:./build/h2db/db/gatewayu"
            username "gatewayu"
            password ""
            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml"
            defaultSchemaName ""
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "src/main/resources/"
        }
        diffLog {
            driver "org.h2.Driver"
            url "jdbc:h2:file:./build/h2db/db/gatewayu"
            username "gatewayu"
            password ""
            changeLogFile project.ext.diffChangelogFile
            referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:com.rps.png.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
            defaultSchemaName ""
            logLevel "debug"
            classpath "$buildDir/classes/java/main"
        }
    }

    runList = project.ext.runList
}

gitProperties {
    failOnNoGitDirectory = false
    keys = ["git.branch", "git.commit.id.abbrev", "git.commit.id.describe"]
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion '${checkstyle_version}'
    configFile file("checkstyle.xml")
    checkstyleTest.enabled = false
}
nohttp {
    source.include "build.gradle", "README.md"
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    implementation.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Inherited version from Spring Boot can't be used because of regressions:
            // To be removed as soon as spring-boot use the same version
            force 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.9.0'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-repositories - JHipster will add additional repositories
}

dependencies {
    // import JHipster dependencies BOM
    if (!project.hasProperty("gae")) {
        implementation platform("io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}")
    }

    // Use ", version: jhipster_dependencies_version, changing: true" if you want
    // to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
    implementation group: "io.github.jhipster", name: "jhipster-framework"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    implementation "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
    implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient"
    implementation "javax.cache:cache-api"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
    implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io"
    implementation "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
    implementation "org.ehcache:ehcache"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
    implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator"
    implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:${liquibase_hibernate5_version}"
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mysql"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul"
    implementation "com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-core"
    implementation "com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov:bucket4j-jcache"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix"
    implementation "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
    implementation ("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2") {
        exclude module: "mapstruct"
    }
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    liquibaseRuntime "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernate_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${spring_boot_version}"
    testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
    }
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
    testImplementation "com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-api:${archunit_junit5_version}"
    testRuntimeOnly "com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine:${archunit_junit5_version}"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
    liquibaseRuntime "com.h2database:h2"
    //jhipster-needle-gradle-dependency - JHipster will add additional dependencies here
}

if (project.hasProperty("gae")) {
    task createPom {
        def basePath = 'build/resources/main/META-INF/maven'
        doLast {
            pom {
                withXml(dependencyManagement.pomConfigurer)
            }.writeTo("${basePath}/${project.group}/${project.name}/pom.xml")
        }
    }
    bootJar.dependsOn = [createPom]
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
    delete "build/resources"
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "6.4.1"
}


if (project.hasProperty("nodeInstall")) {
    node {
        version = "${node_version}"
        npmVersion = "${npm_version}"
        yarnVersion = "${yarn_version}"
        download = true
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
```

This is a JHipster gateway 6.9 with only minor changes from the default. In particular, I didnt' touch the 'gradle-package' which is failing on the Gitlab Runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the [Docker] image you run your job on? I don't see any `image:` specifications in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Make sure it has `npm` installed or make sure that your Gradle scripts contains instructions or tasks for installing it. You should probably set `nodeInstall` property before running the build:

```
if (project.hasProperty("nodeInstall")) {
    node {
        version = "${node_version}"
        npmVersion = "${npm_version}"
        yarnVersion = "${yarn_version}"
        download = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Previous (successul) steps have the -PnodeInstall, but this one has -Pprod. So it is a bug on JHipster part?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you running in docker runners (e.g. gitlab.com)?

Comment: Every job executes in a different container. Jobs do not share the filesystem. So "previous jobs" has nothing to do with the one that fails. You should add all properties in every job.

Comment: I need to recheck but it works on gitlab.com. it seems you have not selected docker while generating the config file (as base images I missing). We provide a base image that brings all required tools. So clearly a small but on our side as node install property should be added when not running in docker.